# Getting messages sent from python KafkaProducer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

My goal is to get data from non-file sources (i.e. generated within a program or sent though an API) and have it sent to a spark stream. To accomplish this, I'm sending the data through a [python-based](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) `KafkaProducer`:

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &
$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic my-topic
$ python 
Python 3.6.1| Anaconda custom (64-bit)
> from kafka import KafkaProducer
> import time
> producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
> producer.send(topic = 'my-topic', value = 'MESSAGE ACKNOWLEDGED', timestamp_ms = time.time())
> producer.close()
> exit()
```

My issue is that nothing appears when checking the topic from the consumer shell script:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --topic my-topic
^C$
```

Is something missing or wrong here? I'm new to spark/kafka/messaging systems, so anything will help. The Kafka version is 0.11.0.0 (Scala 2.11) and no changes are made to the config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the `value_serializer` silently breaks down because I didn't import the json module to the interpreter. Two solutions for this, one is simply import the module and the you'll get `"MESSAGE ACKNOWLEDGED"` (with quotation marks) back. Or you can remove `value_serializer` altogether and convert the `value` string that's being sent in the next line into a byte string (i.e. `b'MESSAGE ACKNOWLEDGED'` for Python 3) so you'll get the message back without quotation marks.

I also switched Kafka to version 0.10.2.1 (Scala 2.11) since there's no confirmation in the Kafka-python documents that says it's compatible with version 0.11.0.0

Answer (score 1):

If you start a consumer after sending messages to a topic, it is possible that the consumer will skip that messages because it will set a topic offset (which could be considered as a "starting point" to read from) to the topic's end. To change that behavior try to add `--from-beginning` option:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic --from-beginning
```

Also you can try `kafkacat`, which is more convenient than Kafka's console consumer and producer (imho). Reading messages from Kafka with `kafkacat` can be performed with the following command:

```
kafkacat -C -b 'localhost:9092' -o beginning -e -D '\n' -t 'my-topic'
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I added `from-beginning` but the result was the same. I also installed kafkacat, redid my steps and ran your command but it still wasn't finding the message.

Comment: @user2361174 just checked your example, and it seems like the producer does not send anything because of `timestamp_ms=time.time()` – if turn on debug logging, the following message will appear in the log: `DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:Exception occurred during message send: <class 'struct.error'>`. Probably `time.time()` returns timestamp in the format  which is unexpected to the producer... So removing that option should do the trick, i.e. `producer.send(topic='my-topic', value='MESSAGE ACKNOWLEDGED')` (current timestamp will be used by default).

Comment: I got rid of the timestamp although nothing is still showing up in the consumer or the kafkacat command. I've saved the command line output here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dretta/spark/master/kafka.log